# How to apply cramer V on 2x2 matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to find the association between variables and cramer V works like a treat for matrices of sizes greater than 2X2. However, for matrices with low frequencies, it does not work well. For the following contingency matrix, i get the result as 0.5. How can I account for the same?

```
  1 2  
a 2 0  
b 0 2
```

Here is my code:

```
def cramers_stat(confusion_matrix):  
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]  
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()  
    return np.sqrt(chi2 / (n*(min(confusion_matrix.shape)-1)))  
result=cramers_stat(confusion_matrix)  
print(result)
```

confusion_matrix is my input, in this case the matrix i mentioned above. I understand for good results, i need a matrix frequency above 5, but for perfect association as the case above I expected the result to be 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compute the Cramér coefficient, you must compute chi2 without [continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity).  For a 2x2 matrix, [`chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) uses continuity correction by default.  So you must tell `chi2_contingency` to not use continuity correction by giving the argument `correction=False`:

```
chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix, correction=False)[0]
```